# Code completion does not works in Instruments UIAutomation script editor

Tags: instruments, code-completion, ios-ui-automation

In only one place in apple docs there is a statement that instruments in 4.2 supports code completion in script editor of UIAutomation. But it doesn't works for me. Is there anything i can do to make it work?

Comment: Does it ever worked for anyone?

Comment: Does it work in the XCode 5.0